# Where can I purchase tefillin according to the Temani/Rambami shitah?

Tags: product-recommendation, rambam, tefilin, yemenite-temani

Not just *tefillin* made of *gewil* (i.e. גויל - unsplit hide), but with the *shin* that goes all the way to the bottom of the *bayith*?

Is there any source for purchasing such *tefillin*?

Comment: Tefillin are made with klaf, per Rambam, Hilchos Tefillin Ch 1

Answer (score 2):

Mo`adhim le-simhah,

Thanks for your inquiry about obtaining *tefillin* according to the Yemenite understanding of the Rambam.

First, you should know that according to the Mishneh Torah, *tefillin* are NOT written on *gewil*, but on *galaf* (i.e. קלף - parchment) [see *Hilkhoth Tefillin* 1:3,8,11]. Not only is writing them on *gewil* not the *halakhah*, it would not be physically possible or practical since it is so thick that your *tefillin* would have to be much larger than even the largest *tefillin* produced today.

As for where to purchase them, as these *tefillin* (i.e. with the baseless "*shin*" extending from the base) are so rare, I would suggest that you get it touch with either Rav Ratzon Arussi, Rav Eliyakim Tzadok, or Rav Mosheh Sarum through *Makhon Mosheh* (www.net-sah.org).

If you cannot find a pair like this, know that such a *shin* (or any at all) is not *me`akev* to their *kashruth* and purchasing a set through any Yemenite/Rambami source would be fine halakhically.

Hope this helps.

Good luck and Kol Tuv.

Comment: I was under the impression the bayith was made of gewil?

Comment: ?  http://www.nosachteiman.co.il

Comment: A *shin* is me'akev, even according to Rambam. See Hilchot sta"m 3:1-2 http://mechon-mamre.org/i/23.htm

Comment: @Yitzchak - It depends on what you are talking about, actually. If you are talking about the 3 and 4-branched shins on either side, then they are not, as is apparent to many rishonim. The "shin" that is me`akev is the one created by the harissim (grooves) in between each bayith in the shel rosh. That is the ONLY one mentioned by the Gemara. And since EVERYONE puts them on today, not having base (as per the questioner) is certainly not me'akev at all, as long as it is a shin. Look into it. The current customs of shins is no older than the Geonim. Kol tuv.

Comment: @EliyahuBenYosef - "Gewil" is a reference to a parchment of unsplit hide, not the thick shoulder skin that most tefillin are made out of. The term you are looking for is "gassoth" ("thick ones"). Of course the hide used to make them is unsplit, but "gewil" generally only refers to the brown parchment. Kol tuv.

Comment: http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=128473 you may be interested

Answer (score 2):

This answer serves as a comprehensive guide where one can purchase Rambam tefillin. If ever this information is outdated please comment and i'll update it.

In my travels to Jerusalem i met a sofer who makes special limited sets of Rambam tefillin in various sizes. His name is Steve Bar Yakov Gindi and I've been to his workshop and seen the quality of the batim he works with. He has a digital storefront but it doesn't list all the options available. The store only mentions tiny sized Rambam tefillin but you can request medium and large sized.

http://milknhoney.co.il/buy-tefillin/

There is a Temani store called Nusach Teiman that sells tefillin at a very reasonable price, but I haven't seen the product with my own eyes.
http://www.nosachteiman.co.il/?CategoryID=1041&ArticleID=5118

Another source is Machon Gewil, sometimes their website works, sometimes it doesn't. Here is the link:

http://www.chayas.com/gevil/

Another sourse is Torath Moshe, note that there seems to be some overlap between them and Machon Gewil. I have spoken to the owner of this website and he was kind enough to tell me that he used to source the tefillin from the Steve the sofer who I mentioned above .Also, their website is unfortunately often down as well:

http://www.torathmoshe.com/store/scribal-items/tephillin/

Answer (score 0):

This answer will be only according to Rambam since that is what you asked. Tefillin may not be written on gewil and are passul if they are. (Hilchot tefillin 1:9) You can find tefillin written on Rambami klaf, according to the (probably) more accurate girsa about what klaf actually is, from [Machon Gewil](http://www.chayas.com/gevil/)

Comment: The questioner asked specifically about "the shin that goes all the way to the bayith" which is a specific interpretation of the shins on either side, i.e. that they have no base. Machon Gewil does not manufacture those. Kol tuv.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase Temani (Yemenite) tefillin [here](http://www.torathmoshe.com/store/scribal-items/tephillin/). It is the only place I know of that sells them. They also sell other Temani things in their store, including mezuzot, Sifrei Torah and Megillot.

I must note they mention specifically the soferim writing on authentic klaf and gevil.

Comment: `It is the only place I know of that sells them` what about the place mentioned in the existing answer?